# Google Chrome or YouTube issue, autoplay channel video conflicts with playing a video from that same page

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, browser, youtube

When I go to a YouTube channel on Google Chrome and in the main window of that channel there is a video playing (like channel's trailer) the auto starting main video keeps playing in background even if I click on another video to watch on that page.  So I have to close that tab, and open the video in another one.
Does anyone have the same problem ?

Comment: This question isn't very clear what your question is. Could you add more detail, or somehow make it more clear to the reader what you are asking?

Comment: which part you didn't understand ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to switch [HTML5 player](https://www.youtube.com/html5) to [flash player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/). I think HTML5 player forced to use on chrome browser  and you cant disable it normally on youtube.
Some not standard ways to swap to flash player for chrome:

1) [Disable Youtube™ HTML5 Player](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/disable-youtube-html5-pla/enmofgaijnbjpblfljopnpdogpldapoc/) chrome extension.

2) Change useragent for example to Firefox with [User-Agent Switcher for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.Do you mean that this is a bug or there is something wrong with my PC ?

Comment: Firstly you should check if this actually solve problem.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your question exactly how you asked it:

**Does anyone have the same problem ?**

I cannot speak for others, but no, I do not have this problem.